Fail to build the docker image with failing to fetch anonymous token
I am new to Docker. I ran net stop winnat and net start winnat in the cmd before. And I ran "docker build ." to create a dock image with node.js again. I failed and got errors:
[+] Building 31.0s (2/2) FINISHED                                                                                           docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 151B                                                                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:14                                                                     31.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:14:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM node:14
   2 |     
   3 |     WORKDIR /app
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: DeadlineExceeded: DeadlineExceeded: DeadlineExceeded: node:14:
failed to resolve source metadata for docker.io/library/node:14: failed to authorize:
DeadlineExceeded: failed to fetch anonymous token:
Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fnode%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io":
dial tcp 54.198.86.24:443: i/o timeout

This is my dockerfile:
FROM node:14
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "app.mjs" ]

I reinstalled Docker again, but also failed.

Did you read the error message?

Yeah, I don't how to fix it. And I searched a lot, there are some similar problems like mine, but they are not about "node:14". So the issues are not exactly same, and it doesn't have the same way to fix the similar problems.

Try docker pull node:14 at first.

Why do you believe the error is related to the node:14 image? Do other images from docker hub work? What about other registries like ghcr.io? Have you tried connecting to the failing URL with other tools like curl? Have you tried pulling images from another network?

@user25009716 docker pull node:14 works for me. Thank you!
